# How does it make sense to use the variable name used to name a function inside that same function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

In this snippet, from the [Angular documentation on `$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), the name of the function is `user` and inside the function they are using a variable of the same name.

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

How does that make sense? And what are the rules around this?

Comment: looks like you missed function parameter in get callback: `User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {`

Comment: Not really. The content of callback function refers to `var user`.

Comment: I think @Rasalom has the right of it, and this is a typo in the docs -- if you search further down in the docs for `$save`, you'll see that code repeated but with `user` being passed into the callback function.

Comment: it definetly points to function param, here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fq5v75w3/

Comment: @Blazemonger so there's an error in the Angular documentation again?

Comment: Apparently so. Tech writers are only human.

Comment: ok, I got it, there is another example in docs with `var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {` I guess it should be with `user` as callback parameter.

Comment: @Blazemonger Is there also an error on the line with `var card = cards[0];` in the same [docs for $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `User.get()`, it returns a promise, and processing continues. When that promise resolves, angular sets the variable you set it to, in this case `user`, to the value of the resolution. It *also* calls the success callback function, so you can safely change it at that point.

To use the above example, here is what happens.

1. you call `User.get({userId:123})
2. `User.get` returns a promise and sets `var user` to that promise
3. processing continues
4. the promise resolves, let's say to `{id:123,name:"Imray"}`
5. angular sets the variable `user` to `{id:123,name:"Imray"}`
6. angular calls your success callback, in which you:
7. set `user.abc` to `true`, so your object now is `{id:123,name:"Imray",abc:true}`
8. you call `user.$save()`, which saves it to the server, etc.

Essentially, there is nothing wrong with it, just be aware of the order of execution.

Comment: So the callback runs as if it's totally independent of the function it's in? As if it was a random function written a few lines down?

Comment: Almost. It runs independent, but called only when the `User.get()` is resolved.

Comment: Aha. It seems a weird way to do it, but I guess it works

Comment: It gives you options. You can just use `var user = User.get({userId:123});` and rely on angular to resolve it, or you can use the callback when resolved to do extra processing. Or both. The example from the docs is meant to show both.

Answer (score 0):

"user" is not name of function, its name of object which is read from given resource.

To be correct. User become proxy which is filled with data when http request is done.

Second parameter - function is callback which is called after user is successfully loaded, so user become fully created object.

So when .get is called it works exactly like that:

- create variable user with "proxy"
- read user from /user/123
- actualize user varible with data and "resource's methods" ($save, $delete...)
- call given function callback in which:

  - set abc in user object
  - save it back to the resource  ($save introduces POST to /user/123

In documentation you can read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource - 
(part Usage/Returns)

> "It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods."

"user" doesnt have to be passed as parameter because user is set before callback is called.

Comment: I mean it like user is assigned before its read from resource. It is not promise. Its just empty object which you can pass to your template and its become filled(and updated) when reading resource is done)

Comment: I have added exact part of documentation